# How do I remove WSS-Password Type requirement in WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I built a WCF service with basicHttpBinding with the binding configuration as shown below

```
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

When I host this service on IIS add this in SoapUI for testing, it forces me to set `WSS-Password Type` as `PasswordText`.

The consumer of this service uses some tool to access service methods claim, they can't supply password type in their tool or language. (out of topic).

So, I have tried various ways setting security mode as None, Message but nothing worked.

I need to receive user name and password so non-authenticated requests are not the requirements here.

```
<behavior name="customBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                    customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="CustomServices.Library.UserValidator, CustomServices"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
```

How do I host this service to accept user name and password but not password-type as a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

SOAP UI properties seem to simply construct the same SOAP elements which you can write by hand. For instance, after adding a header my whole test message would look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Header>
     <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-12" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>john1</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
     </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetData>
         <tem:value>123</tem:value>
      </tem:GetData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The `Security` header passes all the user credentials in the above example.
I presume that it's a basic functionality to send messages in the SOAP format when dealing with WCF-services and your client can easily tap into it, can't they?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's relevant to the question :(

Comment: You wrote that "the consumer of this service uses some tool to access service methods claim, they can't supply password type in their tool or language. (out of topic).". I showed you how you can supply this password type without SOAP UI naturally. I reckon that's relevant to the SOAP standard that you have to send a password type. One more approach is to turn off customUserNamePasswordValidatorType and control credentials in your service methods or MessageInspectors.